# Windows has triggered a breakpoint when free memory

Tags: c, memory

I am getting following run time error when freeing 2D dynamic array in C.
**

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint

**

This is my code:

```
int splitString()
{
    char source[] = "str1,str2,str3,str4";
    char *token = NULL;
    char **rowIndexes = NULL;
    int size = 0, index = 0;

    rowIndexes = malloc(sizeof(char));//allocate memory for dynamic array
    if (rowIndexes == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory allocation failed");
    }

    token = strtok(source, ",");
    while (token)//split string into tokens to ","
    {
        rowIndexes = realloc(rowIndexes, sizeof(char*)*(++size));//realloate memory if needed
        if (rowIndexes == NULL)
        {
            printf("memory allocation failed");
            return -1;
        }

        rowIndexes[size - 1] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        free(rowIndexes[index]);
    }
    free(rowIndexes);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please help me to figure out the error.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` does not allocate memory. It just returns pointer to the original string and it manipulates original string. 
You should not pass `const char*` to the `strtok`.

Your program does not allocate memory for `rowIndexes[index]` so trying to call for free without allocating memory will leads to Segmentation fault.
Which caused the break.

Your program trying to free static memory. Calling free on pointers which were not returned by dynamic memory allocating functions will lead to Undefined behaviour.

Comment: `source` isn't const, and it isn't static.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes source is not const and static but information is generic. Is that confusing? In the last paragraph i was refereed static memory not the static source.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` does not return a dynamically allocated string, it only returns a pointer into the string it parses (which it modifies).

You should duplicate the token manually,

```
rowIndexes[size - 1] = strdup(token);
```